# C Programming - Airline Reservation System - Why isn't my save file function working?

Tags: c, struct

```
#include <stdio.h>  
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <conio.h>


struct airlines{
    char name[50];
    char origin[50];
    char destination[50];
    char dtime[50];
    char atime[50];
    char age[50];
}
struct airlines *p;
typedef struct airlines lines[50];

void reserve(struct airlines *p);
void edit(struct airlines *p, int newent);
void search(lines *p, int newent);
void AgeS();
void OriginS();
void DestinationS();
void deletecus(lines *p, int newent, int del);
void display(struct airlines *p, int newent);
void displayall(lines *p, int newent);
void saveFile(struct airlines *p);


int main(){
    
    int sel;
    int newent=0 , editcust, del;
    lines airlinesnew;
    begin = stream = NULL;
    
    do {
    printf("\n\n\t*******************************************************************");
    printf("\n\t                  BREEZE AIRLINES ONLINE BOOKING                 ");
    printf("\n\t*******************************************************************");
    printf("\n\n\t\t1. Reserve a seat");
    printf("\n\n\t\t2. Edit a reservation");
    printf("\n\n\t\t3. Search existing reservations");
    printf("\n\n\t\t4. Delete existing reservations");
    printf("\n\n\t\t5. Display existing reservations");
    printf("\n\n\t\t6. Exit program");
    printf("\n\n\t\tWhich option would you like to choose?: ", &sel);
    scanf("%d", &sel);
    system("cls");
    switch (sel){
        case 1:
            reserve(&airlinesnew[newent]);
            newent++;
            break;
        case 2:
            displayall(&airlinesnew, newent);
            printf("\nWhich entry would you like to edit?: ");
            scanf("%d", &editcust);
            edit(&airlinesnew[editcust-1], newent);
            break;
        case 3:
            search(&airlinesnew, newent);
            break;
        case 4:
            displayall(&airlinesnew, newent);
            printf("Which entry do you want to delete?: ");
            scanf("%d", &del);
            deletecus(&airlinesnew, newent, del);
            newent--;
            break;
        case 5:
            displayall(&airlinesnew, newent);
            break;
        case 6:
            saveFile(&airlinesnew[newent]);
            break;
        default:
            printf("\nInvalid Choice ");
            printf("\nPlease select only from 1-6 ");
    }
    } while (sel != 6);
    return 0;
}

void reserve(struct airlines *p){
    
    printf("\n\tReservation Details");
    printf("\n\tName: ");
    scanf(" %[^\n]s", &(*p).name);
    printf("\n\tAge: ");
    scanf(" %[^\n]s", &(*p).age);
    printf("\n\tOrigin: ");
    scanf(" %[^\n]s", &(*p).origin);
    printf("\n\tDestination: ");
    scanf(" %[^\n]s", &(*p).destination);
    printf("\n\tTime of departure (use military time): ");
    scanf(" %[^\n]s", &(*p).dtime);
    printf("\n\tTime of arrival (use military time): ");
    scanf(" %[^\n]s", &(*p).atime);
    system("cls");
}

void edit(struct airlines *p, int newent){
    
    char nname[50];
    char nage[50];
    char norigin[50];
    char ndestination[50];
    char ndtime[50];
    char natime[50];

    display( &(*p), newent-1 );
    printf("\nEditing the entry: ");
    
    printf("\n\t New Name: ");
    scanf(" %[^\n]s", &nname );
    strcpy( (*p).name,  nname );
    
    printf("\n\t New age: ");
    scanf(" %d", &nage );
    strcpy( (*p).age,  nage );
    
    printf("\n\t New Origin: ");
    scanf(" %[^\n]s", &norigin );
    strcpy( (*p).origin,  norigin );
    
    printf("\n\t New Destination: ");
    scanf(" %[^\n]s", &ndestination );
    strcpy( (*p).destination,  ndestination );
    
    printf("\n\t New time of departure (use military time): ");
    scanf(" %[^\n]s", &ndtime );
    strcpy( (*p).dtime,  ndtime );
    
    printf("\n\t New time of arrival (use military time): ");
    scanf(" %[^\n]s", &natime );
    strcpy( (*p).atime,  natime );
    system("cls");
}


void search(lines *p, int newent){
    int sel1;
    char Ageint[50];
    char Originint[50];
    char Destinationint[50];
    
    do {
        printf ("\nWhich heading would you like to search:");
        printf ("\n1. Age");
        printf ("\n2. Origin");
        printf ("\n3. Destination");
        printf ("\n4. Return");
        printf ("\nHeading number: ");
        scanf ("%d", &sel1);

        switch (sel1)
        {
        case 1: 
        printf ("\nEnter age: ");
        scanf ("%d", &Ageint);
        for (int i = 0; i < newent; i++){
        if( strcmp( (*p)[i].age, Ageint ) == 0 ){
            display( &(*p)[i] , i );
                }
            }
        break;
        case 2:
        printf ("\nEnter origin: ");
        scanf(" %[^\n]s", &Originint );
        for (int i = 0; i < newent; i++){
        if( strcmp( (*p)[i].origin, Originint ) == 0 ){
            display( &(*p)[i] , i );
                }
            }
        break;
        case 3:
        printf ("\nEnter destination: ");
        scanf(" %[^\n]s", &Destinationint );
        for (int i = 0; i < newent; i++){
        if( strcmp( (*p)[i].destination, Destinationint ) == 0 ){
            display( &(*p)[i] , i );
                }
            }
        break;
        case 4:
            main();
        default:
            printf("\nInvalid Choice ");
            printf("\nPlease select only from 1-4 ");
        }
    } while (sel1 != 4);
}

void deletecus(lines *p, int newent, int del){
    int i;
    
    for( i = del-1; i < newent; i++ ){
        strcpy( (*p)[i].name,  (*p)[i+1].name );
        strcpy( (*p)[i].age,  (*p)[i+1].age );
        strcpy( (*p)[i].origin,  (*p)[i+1].origin );
        strcpy( (*p)[i].destination,(*p)[i+1].destination);
        strcpy( (*p)[i].dtime,  (*p)[i+1].dtime );
        strcpy( (*p)[i].atime,  (*p)[i+1].atime );
    }
}

void display(struct airlines *p, int newent){
    printf("\nReservation list:");
    printf("\n");
    printf("Passport No. %d\n", newent+1);
    printf("Name: %s", (*p).name);
    printf("\n");
    printf("Age: %s", (*p).age);
    printf("\n");
    printf("Origin: %s", (*p).origin);
    printf("\n");
    printf("Destination: %s", (*p).destination);
    printf("\n");
    printf("Time of departure: %s", (*p).dtime);
    printf("\n");
    printf("Time of Arrival: %s", (*p).atime);
    printf("\n");
}

void displayall(lines *p, int newent){
    int i;
    for (i=0;i<newent;i++){
        display(&(*p)[i], i);
    }
}

void saveFile(struct airlines *p)
{
    FILE *fptr;
    fptr = fopen("reserved_seats", "a+");
    
    if(!fptr)
    {
        printf("Error\n");
        return;
    }

    fprintf(fptr, "%15s", (*p).name);
    fprintf(fptr, "%15s", (*p).age);
    fprintf(fptr, "%15s", (*p).origin);
    fprintf(fptr, "%15s", (*p).destination);
    fprintf(fptr, "%15s", (*p).dtime);
    fprintf(fptr, "%15s", (*p).atime);
    fprintf(fptr, "\n");
    
    printf("\nSaved successfully");
    fclose(fptr);
}
```

So this is my current code for an airline reservation system. One of the functions needed is by saving the data that are inputted, so that when the program is closed it will still display the saved data as it will be accessing a saved file. But upon doing the save function, the program does create a file, but instead of it having the inputted data, it just has a file with nothing in it. Please help

Comment: Unrelated: `(*p).member` can also be written as `p->member`.

Answer (score 0):

When you call `saveFile()` the `newent` index is not pointing to the last entry in the array; it's pointing to the first "empty" space in the array.

You need to specify the index you want to save... or, if you trust your users, just save `newent - 1`

```
case 6:
    if (newent > 0) saveFile(&airlinesnew[newent - 1]); // save the last entry
    break;
```

---

To save all entries you need a loop. Either call your function (possibly rename `saveEntry()`) `newent` times, or use a new function (`saveArray()`) which takes the whole array and the number of valid elements

```
    case 6:
        // assuming newent has the number of valid entries
        for (int i = 0; i < newent; i++) {
            saveEntry(&airlinesnew[i]);
        }
```

or

```
void saveArray(struct airlines *a, int n); // prototype

// ...

    case 6:
        // assuming newent has the number of valid entries
        saveArray(airlinesnew, newent);
        break;

// ...

void saveArray(struct airlines *a, int n) {
    // open file
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        // write a[i] to file
    }
    // close file
}
```

Comment: May also want to point out that even after that is fixed `saveFile` is fundamentally inadequate as it only attempts to save one entry and not the entire valid data.

Comment: Yes @kaylum, `saveFile()` is badly worded (... or badly implemented)

Comment: Thank you for helping guys, I did realize that it does attempt to only save one entry, how do I change it so that it would save the whole valid data? I'm really new to this and help is badly needed, thank you so much.

Comment: @BuggritZ: added options to save it all in my answer.

Comment: @pmg how would I be able to create a function that would edit the content of the file that I have saved? For example, I was able to input a name in the file, and that I was able to save it, how would I be able to edit it and the file would update?

Comment: The easiest method is to always read and write the whole file (possibly creating a backup). Alternatively, use `fseek()` to position the next read/write at the proper position (which, for text files, if difficult to find). Or... use a proper database.

Answer (score 0):

There some points that need to be addressed in your code:

---

**First:**

As already mentioned in the comments, your approach to saving/loading data is bad.
Read the entire file once the program starts, load it into a data structure, and write it back when the program stops. Define two functions to do so:

```c
int count_file_lines(FILE *stream)
{
    int n;
    for (n = 0; EOF != (scanf("%*[^\n]"), scanf("%*c")); ++n)
        ;
    
    rewind(stream);
    return n;
}
```

```c
int load_file(const char *filename, char **lines, int *n)
{
    FILE *stream = fopen(filename, "r");
    if (!stream)
        return 0;
    
    *n = count_file_lines(stream);
    lines = malloc(*n * sizeof *lines);
    if (!lines) {
        fclose(stream);
        return 0;
    }
    
    char line[1024]; // Can be more
    int i = 0;
    
    while(fgets(line, sizeof line, stream)) {
        line[strcspn(line, "\n")] = '\0'; // Remove \n read by fgets()
        lines[i++] = strdup(line);
    }
    
    fclose(stream);
    return 1;
}
```

```c
int save_file(const char *filename, char **lines, int n)
{
    FILE *stream = fopen(filename, "w");
    if (!stream)
        return 0;
    
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        fprintf(stream, "%s\n", lines[i]);
    
    fclose(stream);
    return 1;
}
```

Then use `sscanf()` for parsing.

---

**Second:**

Don't use `scanf()` to read input. It is very error-prone. Use `fgets()` instead and `sscanf()` for parsing:

```c
fgets(string, sizeof string, stdin));
string[strcspn(string, "\n")] = '\0'; // Replace '\n' with '\0'

if (sscanf(string, "%d", &intval) != 1) { // Get an int and check for errors
    // Error code
}
```

---

Your main code should look like this:

```c
int main()
{
    do {
        // Print menu
        
        // Read selection
        
        // If selection is valid, load_file()
        
        // switch-case ...
        // case 6: save_file()
    } while (sel != 6);
}
```